# Appcelerator Titanium startMonitoringForRegion

Tags: iphone, android, titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I am using Appcelerator Titanium for building my mobile app(iphone + android).
I found titanium.geolocation in their documents , but I couldn't find any method such as  "startMonitoringForRegion" or "startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges" as we use to find in iOS. but it has properties defined as "ERROR_REGION_MONITORING_DENIED", so there must be some region monitoring method.

So is it not defined in documents or am I missing something. I tried Googling but couldn't find it.

Bascically all I want is to present user with some alert when user enters a particular region, even when the app is in background ( as I used to do it with startMonitoringForRegion in iOS). So is it possible with Titanium. Please Help.

Comment: I am still not able to find any perfect answer .. could someone from appcelerator or an expert with this .. please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"For applications that do not need a regular stream of location events, you should consider using the `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` method to start the delivery of events instead. This method is more appropriate for the majority of applications that just need an initial user location fix and need updates only when the user moves a significant distance. This interface delivers new events only when it detects changes to the device’s associated cell towers, resulting in less frequent updates and significantly better power usage."

By that standard that Apple defines it would seem that all you need is to set the `Titanium.Geolocation.distanceFilter` so that the event continues to fire every * meters

There is no documentation on it directly however if you check out the KS resources you'll see the `geolocation.js` file uses several abilities not documented. I had to basically copy it and strip out what I didn't need for my app.

https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink/blob/master/Resources/examples/geolocation.js#L345

`startMonitoringForRegion` should be the same idea but you will need to set the `accuracy constant` as defined in this [documentation](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Geolocation-module).

Comment: yes definitely i can set all those.. but the thing is "startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges" and "startMonitoringForRegion"  wakes up the app in background even when the app has been supended and the device enters the monitored region... but that is not the case with geolocation listener

Comment: and moreever i just realise that cell tower may change in another 1 metres or may change after 30 metres, depending on the network present , so I cannot just set Distance Filter and achieve the functionality

Comment: https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink/blob/master/Resources/bg.js as to your first comment you could put the TiGeo Event in the background but as to your second one that seems like a faulty solution also...

Comment: although not perfect answer I wanted, but the close answer till date

Answer (score -1):

you can try and attach a listener to `regionChanged` event

http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Map.MapView-object

Comment: map functions are only called when u diplay a map and moreover it will not work in background .. thnx for trying.. anyone else pls ..